# Incorrect Syntax near when using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql

can someone help me about this error on dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(10)=null
EXEC ('select ISNULL('+@value+',125)')
```

and error message like this :

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: One thing you can do to help troubleshoot is use the PRINT function if you're using SSMS. So you can do `PRINT CAST(('select ISNULL('+@value+',125)') AS TEXT)` and it will write out the dynamic SQL to the "Messages" tab in SSMS. Then you can see the actual text which will help you figure out where the error might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@value` is defaulted to NULL so your `expression` will entirely be invalid. use `literal 'null'`.

```
declare @value varchar(10)=null
declare @strsql  varchar(max) = 'select isnull('+coalesce(@value, 'null')+', 125)'
exec (@strsql)
```

**or**

```
declare @value varchar(10)='null'
declare @strsql  varchar(max) = 'select isnull('+@value+', 125)'
exec (@strsql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(10)=null
DECLARE @sc VARCHAR(100) = 'select ISNULL('+@value+',125)'
EXEC(@sc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute dynamic.
Simply:

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(10)=null
SELECT ISNULL(@value, 125)
```